# Custom/Varying delays on a HSpice digital vector file

Tags: hspice

I've been trying to find a way to set custom timings for signals coming from a digital vector file in a simple test circuit with 4 inputs and 4 outputs as shown.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwY5GW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I used 4 of these to easily observe input/output behavior.

My digital vector file code is :

```
radix 1111 
vname v<4> v<3> v<2> v<1>
io iiii
tunit ns
period 10
trise 0.01
tfall 0.01
vih 1
vil 0

0000
0001
0010
0011
```

as well as some more tabular data that isn't included.

So for example, I want 0000 to occur at 0ns, then 0001 at 15 ns, then 0010 at 16 ns, and 0011 at 20ns. It seems like there is no way to set a custom delay in the .vec file using vector file commands other than inserting a bunch of 0000's so I was wondering if it would be possible to do that through the actual .sp file that uses my digital vector file.

If it helps, this is how I used the vector file in my spice file:

```
r9 vout<4> 0 1e3
r8 v<4> vout<4> 1e3
r7 vout<3> 0 1e3
r6 v<3> vout<3> 1e3
r5 vout<2> 0 1e3
r4 v<2> vout<2> 1e3
r1 vout<1> 0 1e3
r0 v<1> vout<1> 1e3

.vec 'tabvec.vec'

.print v(*)
.probe v(*)
.options post

.tran 1n 200n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So for example, I want 0000 to occur at 0ns, then 0001 at 15 ns, then 0010 at 16 ns, and 0011 at 20ns. ...

In this PDF file:

https://www.bioee.ee.columbia.edu/courses/cad/html/vector_file.pdf

on page 39 it says the following about tabular data:

[image]

So I'd try not using the `period` directive and adding timestamps to your tabular data. That page of the PDF also contains this example:

```
; format: time vector
0 000101010
10 011010101
20 000101010
```